# JMeter : How do I Remove local HTTP Header Manager from each Requests in the Thread Group?

Tags: http-headers, jmeter, beanshell

Here is a link to image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/fIg3R.png

I have local Header manger for each request. I also have Global one. [Please look at the image] I want to remove local Header manager for all requests.

I tried it by creating a preprocessor and writing "sampler.getHeaderManager().removeHeaderNamed("HTTP Header manager");" inside it. But, It's not working. Because of this, It cannot authenticate credentials.

I also tried "sampler.getHeaderManager().remove(0)". This didn't work too. remove(1) ignores the global header manager.

Comment: Here is my hack. Care must be taken care while following the below steps. I am not responsible if some mishaps happens :) I follow this trick to replace dynamic values. 1. Take a backup of your JMeter script. 2. Open the script in the notepad++. 3. Find the `Header Manager` tags. It goes something like this `<hashTree><HeaderManager guiclass="HeaderPanel" testclass="HeaderManager" testname="HTTP Header Manager" enabled="true"><collectionProp name="HeaderManager.headers"/></HeaderManager><hashTree/>` 4. Replace it with empty value using `Find and Replace`. 5. Save it and open in JMeter.

Comment: @NaveenKumarNamachivayam Thank you. I really appreciate your answer. But every Header manager has different parameter values. There is no way I can replace it using find and replace. That's why I was looking some way to do it programmatically. I googled it and tried things I have mentioned but nothing worked.

Comment: You can use `Regular Expression` in notepad++. It is simple to write. :) Just google.

Comment: @NaveenKumarNamachivayam Thanks. It worked. But, just curious now. Do you know how it's done through BeanShell PreProcessor? Because, I tried everything I found on the internet. I don't know where I am going wrong. It would be great if I can do it using BeanShell.

Comment: Let me check in BeanShell. May I post my answer? Will you accept it? Thanks!

Comment: @NaveenKumarNamachivayam Of course. Why not?

Comment: @NaveenKumarNamachivayam But, to accept your answer, you want to answer it as an answer not as a comment.

Comment: yes. I will post my answer. Thanks.

Comment: Please check my answer and accept it :) Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is my suggestion. Care must be taken care while following the below steps. I follow this trick to replace dynamic values.

1. Take a **backup of your JMeter script**.
2. Open the script in the `notepad++`.
3. Find the Header Manager tags. It goes something like this 
   `<hashTree><HeaderManager guiclass="HeaderPanel" testclass="HeaderManager" testname="HTTP Header Manager" enabled="true"><collectionProp name="HeaderManager.headers"/></HeaderManager><hashTree/>`

If you have many `Header Manager Name` and its name unique, you can use `regular expression` in notepad++.

Reg ex syntax in `notepad++`

`<hashTree><HeaderManager guiclass="HeaderPanel" testclass="HeaderManager" testname="(.+)" enabled="true"><collectionProp name="HeaderManager.headers"/>
</HeaderManager><hashTree/>`

[image: Reg Ex in Notepad++]

4. Replace it with `empty` value using `Find and Replace`.

> While replacing, please take care of `<hashtree></hashtree>` tags, any conflicts will result in corruption in the script. Use `Test Plan Check Tool` plugin to validate your test plan. Please visit this link to know more https://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/TestPlanCheckTool/

5. Save it and open in JMeter.

### Before

[image: Before]

### After

[image: After]

Answer (score -1):

1. Give your "global" header manager a different name
2. Run your test via [Taurus](http://gettaurus.org/) tool. Taurus naturally supports JMeter tests execution and adds some extra features on top, for instance [Modifications for Existing Scripts](http://gettaurus.org/docs/JMeter/#Modifications-for-Existing-Scripts). Assuming your test is called `test.jmx` the relevant Taurus config file will be as simple as:

   ```
   ---
   execution:
     scenario:
       script: test.jmx
       modifications:
         disable: HTTP Header Manager
   ```

   If you save it as i.e. `test.yml` and execute Taurus as:

   ```
   bzt test.yml -gui
   ```

   a JMeter instance will launch and open your script with Header Manager elements disabled.

See [Navigating your First Steps Using Taurus](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/navigating-your-first-steps-using-taurus) article for more information on the approach.

Currently it is not possible to fully remove test elements programmatically, you can only remove individual headers. Going forward you might want to untick `Capture HTTP Headers` box under [HTTP(S) Test Script Recorder](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP(S)_Test_Script_Recorder) in order to avoid this situation:

[image: HTTP(S) Test Script Recorder Capture Headers]

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer.  Sorry to bother you but I have seen posts and blog saying to use "sampler.getHeaderManager().removeHeaderNamed("HTTP Header manager");" or  "sampler.getHeaderManager().remove(0)". Why is it not working? Any idea?  I have seen your comments and you also said to use this.

Comment: Why you are asking me instead of asking the people who wrote those "blogs and posts"? 

You can remove a single header, i.e. `Content-Type` via `sampler.getHeaderManager().removeHeaderNamed("Content-Type");`. You can remove another header, i.e. `Authorization` by adding `sampler.getHeaderManager().removeHeaderNamed("Authorization");`. There is no possibility to remove Header Manager in the runtime.